# Multi-domain Routing and SSL on Node.js

Tags: node.js, ssl, routes, google-cloud-platform

I have a Node.js app that serves http requests. Users can signup, create an account and when they do, I generate a subdomain for them to use. eg username.example.com. This is fairly straight forward to do and can be served over ssl using a single certificate.

I would like to give the option for the user to use their own domain. From Node.js this isn't too difficult either. I can check the hostname and look up the account details from there.

I'm struggling to work out how to generate ssl's for these custom domains though.

Right now, my app runs on Heroku, but I also have a staging build on Google's App Engine, so I don't deal with the web server directly. In fact, I don't even know what it is, it could be Nginx or Apache.

To keep the conversation focused, let's stay I want to stick to app engine. When a user adds their own domain, I store it in the database. How would I auto generate an SSL for this?

Answer (score 1):

I thought of general steps for this, but there is one showstopper which I'm not sure it is possible to workaround. The steps will be:

1. Map the user's domain to your application and configure the DNS records. You can do that with the `gcloud` commands: steps and general description outlined in this [Mapping Custom Domains](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/mapping-custom-domains) docs page (notice that you can switch between *Console* and *GCloud* in the boxes). There is also a possibility of doing that within the Cloud Console, however as you've mentioned you're interested in the programmatic approach. If you prefer to configure the custom domain from the API, the same functionality exists in [App Engine Admin API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/reference/rest/#rest-resource-v1appsdomainmappings) with its REST resource for domain mappings.

**Possible showstopper** (source: [Mapping Custom Domains](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/mapping-custom-domains#adding_a_custom_domain_for_your_application)) :

> Verify that you are the owner of your domain through Webmaster Central

2. After that, App Engine provisions a managed certificate and then handles renewing/revoking it. [Securing Custom Domains with SSL](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/securing-custom-domains-with-ssl) is still in beta, but it offers the functionality that you need.